# How to show exact number in Numeric Range Natie Filter in Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I have Numeric Range filter with values 201401,201402 etc.. but in the filter in place of showing the exact value it is showing as 201K ..how can I get the exact value. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Numerical Range doesn't have that option. If you want a filter that matches 201401,201402 exactly then using the value filter is more useful.

If this is an id or a high cardinality column, use "Dynamically search all filter values" so the ui can load faster.